# if condition for partial argument in map

Tags: scala

I understand how to use if in map. For example, `val result = list.map(x => if (x % 2 == 0) x * 2 else x / 2)`.

However, I want to use `if` for only part of the arguments.

```
val inputColumns = List(
  List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),   // first "column"
  List(4, 6, 5, 7, 12, 15)  // second "column"
)
inputColumns.zipWithIndex.map{ case (col, idx) => if (idx == 0) col * 2 else col / 10}
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but integer literal found.

inputColumns.zipWithIndex 
res4: List[(List[Int], Int)] = List((List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),0), (List(4, 6, 5, 7, 12, 15),1))
```

I have searched the error info but have not found a solution.

Why my code is not 'legal' in Scala? Is there a better way to write it? Basically, I want to do a pattern matching and then do something on other arguments.

Comment: are you trying to multiply the list by 2 and devide by 10? and there is no then keyword in if else scala

Comment: you should be getting `error: value * is not a member of List[Int]` error . are you sure that you are still getting `error: ';' expected but integer literal found.` error after you corrected the code? By the way I have explained in the answer below :)

Comment: `zipWithIndex.map{case (c,0)=>c.map(_*2);case (c,_)=>c.map(_/10)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain your problem another way, `inputColumns` has type `List[List[Int]]`. You can verify this in the *Scala REPL*:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_161).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val inputColumns = List(
 |   List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),   // first "column"
 |   List(4, 6, 5, 7, 12, 15)  // second "column"
 | )
inputColumns: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), List(4, 6, 5, 7, 12, 15))
```

Now, when you call `.zipWithIndex` on that list, you end up with a `List[(List[Int], Int)]` - that is, a list of a tuple, in which the first tuple type is a `List[Int]` (the column) and the second is an `Int` (the index):

```
scala> inputColumns.zipWithIndex
res0: List[(List[Int], Int)] = List((List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),0), (List(4, 6, 5, 7, 12, 15),1))
```

Consequently, when you try to apply a `map` function to this list, `col` is a `List[Int]` and not an `Int`, and so `col * 2` makes no sense - you're multiplying a `List[Int]` by `2`. You then also try to divide the list by 10, obviously.

```
scala> inputColumns.zipWithIndex.map{ case(col, idx) => if(idx == 0) col * 2 else col / 10 }
<console>:13: error: value * is not a member of List[Int]
       inputColumns.zipWithIndex.map{ case(col, idx) => if(idx == 0) col * 2 else col / 10 }
                                                                         ^
<console>:13: error: value / is not a member of List[Int]
       inputColumns.zipWithIndex.map{ case(col, idx) => if(idx == 0) col * 2 else col / 10 }
                                                                                      ^
```

In order to resolve this, it depends what you're trying to achieve. If you want a single list of integers, and then zip those so that each value has an associated index, you should call `flatten` on `inputColumns` before calling `zipWithIndex`. This will result in `List[(Int, Int)]`, where the first value in the tuple is the `column` value, and the second is the index. Your map function will then work correctly without modification:

```
scala> inputColumns.flatten.zipWithIndex.map{ case(col, idx) => if(idx == 0) col * 2 else col / 10 }
res3: List[Int] = List(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

Of course, you no longer have separate columns.

If you wish each value in each list to have an associated index, you need to firstly map `inputColumns` into two zipped lists, using `inputColumns.map(_.zipWithIndex)` to create a `List[List[(Int, Int)]]` - a list of a list of `(Int, Int)` tuples:

```
scala> inputColumns.map(_.zipWithIndex)
res4: List[List[(Int, Int)]] = List(List((1,0), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (5,4), (6,5)), List((4,0), (6,1), (5,2), (7,3), (12,4), (15,5)))
```

We can now apply your original map function to the result of the `zipWithIndex` operation:

```
scala> inputColumns.map(_.zipWithIndex.map { case (col, idx) => if(idx == 0) col * 2 else col / 10 })
res5: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), List(8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
```

The result is another `List[List[Int]]` with each internal list being the results of your map operation on the original two input columns.

On the other hand, if `idx` is meant to be the index of the column, and not of each value, and you want to multiply all of the values in the first column by 2 and divide all of the values in the other columns by 10, then you need to change your original `map` function to map across each column, as follows:

```
scala> inputColumns.zipWithIndex.map {
     |   case (col, idx) => {
     |     if(idx == 0) col.map(_ * 2) // Multiply values in first column by 1
     |     else col.map(_ / 10) // Divide values in all other columns by 10
     |   }
     | }
res5: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12), List(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
```

Let me know if you require any further clarification...

**UPDATE**:

The use of `case` in `map` is a common *Scala* shorthand. If a higher-order function takes a single argument, something such as this:

```
def someHOF[A, B](x: A => B) = //...
```

and you call that function like this (with what *Scala* terms a *partial function* - a function consisting solely of a list of `case` statements):

```
someHOF {
  case expr1 => //...
  case expr2 => //...
  ...
}
```

then *Scala* treats it as a kind-of shorthand for:

```
someHOF {a =>
  a match {
    case expr1 => //...
    case expr2 => //...
    ...
  }
}
```

or, being slightly more terse,

```
someHOF {
  _ match {
    case expr1 => //...
    case expr2 => //...
    ...
  }
}
```

For a `List`, for example, you can use it with functions such as `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, etc.

In the case of your `map` function, the sole argument is a tuple, and the sole `case` statement acts to *break open* the tuple and expose its contents. That is:

```
val l = List((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
l.map { case(a, b) => println(s"First is $a, second is $b") }
```

is equivalent to:

```
l.map {x =>
  x match {
    case (a, b) => println(s"First is $a, second is $b")
  }
}
```

and both will output:

```
First is 1, second is 2
First is 3, second is 4
First is 5, second is 6
```

Note: This latter is a bit of a dumb example, since `map` is supposed to map (i.e. change) the values in the list into new values in a new list. If all you were doing was printing the values, this would be better:

```
val l = List((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
l.foreach { case(a, b) => println(s"First is $a, second is $b") }
```

Comment: Awesome! Could you explain how does `case` work here? Is there another way to write it? Does it do pattern matching?

Comment: @JohnHass I'll update my answer shortly with an explanation.

Comment: @JohnHass I just expanded my updated answer with some further information. Let me know if that explains things better...

Comment: Excellent!! I asked a related question in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020570/why-zip-does-not-work-with-match-case-in-scala

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to *multiply a list by 2* when you do `col * 2` as `col` is `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` when `idx` is `0`, **which is not possible** and similar is the case with else part `col / 10`

If you are trying to *multiply the elements of first list by 2* and *devide the elements of rest of the list by 10* then you should be doing the following

```
inputColumns.zipWithIndex.map{ case (col, idx) => if (idx == 0) col.map(_*2) else col.map(_/10)}
```

Even **better approach** would be to use `match` `case`

```
inputColumns.zipWithIndex.map(x => x._2 match {
  case 0 => x._1.map(_*2)
  case _ => x._1.map(_/10)
})
```